# Can you artificially create molecules with a machine?

Tags: molecules

Is it possible to create molecules with machines? For example: you shoot one oxygen-atom $(\ce O)$ on one diatomic hydrogen $(\ce{H2})$ to create one water molecule $(\ce{H2O})$.

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/232530/2451

Comment: You kinda can, but that would be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: Surely you can create any molecule with automation. MIT have done it. Is there another example as water isn't artificial

Comment: Sounds like a replicator from Star Trek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds to me like molecular beam chemistry. Within a vacuum chamber, you can create and collimate a focused "beam" of moving atoms or molecules and direct it to hit a stationary target or another beam. You can use spectroscopy to study the species that are formed. The idea is to look for and characterize reactive intermediates or transition states between starting materials and products. But if you were to create a familiar species such as water in this manner, it is not "artificial" water, but the real thing.

Maybe there is a physical chemist out there that can elaborate further on molecular beams.

Comment: First Thanks! I think the "artificial" is misleading, I meant it so: "Create Molecules Artificially" ...without the Chemical Reactions!